# Why required notice form didn't show up in myModal

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

This is my code of mymodal :

```html
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Insert Gejala</h4>
            </div>
            <form enctype="multipart/form-data" role="form" action="tambahgejalakeproses.php" method="POST">
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Nama Gejala</label>
                    <input class="form-control" name="nama" type="text" placeholder="Masukkan Nama Gejala" required>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Tingkat Gejala</label>
                    <input class="form-control" name="tingkat" type="text" placeholder="Masukkan Tingkat Gejala" required>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Skor Gejala</label>
                    <input class="form-control" name="skor" type="text" placeholder="Masukkan Skor Gejala" required>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Batas Bawah</label>
                    <input class="form-control" name="bawah" type="text" placeholder="Masukkan Nilai Bawah Gejala" required>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Batas Atas</label>
                    <input class="form-control" name="atas" type="text" placeholder="Masukkan Nilai Atas Gejala" required>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Tambahkan</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

i want to ask , why required notice of input text didn't show up.
when i press submit button , form will be redirect to proses of insert data to database, although my input text still empty.

Please Help Me .
Thanks Before

Comment: it working fine in jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/sheshu036/o6kb9poy/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One question to consider is what browser are you using?

In order for the `required` attribute to work appropriately, it needs to be an HTML5 document.  So, your doctype at the very top of your HTML needs to look like this: **`<!DOCTYPE html>`**. I would also recommend adding the `aria-required` attribute to your input to make your form more accessible.

```
<input class="form-control" name="skor" type="text" placeholder="Masukkan Skor Gejala" required="required" aria-required="true" />
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: My problem finally been solved, i had to use validation.js , because i use bootstrap 3 for my template, and i must add data-toggle="validation" inside my form.
Haha. poor me. 

Thanks Before ^_^

Comment: @HeddySebastian, yes that is a good alternative.  I use it regularly.  I was going to suggest, but figured I would just try to point you in the right direction for the problem you mentioned.  Glad you got it figured out!